# Are there any main differences between MySQL (MariaDB), PostgreSQL, Oracle, Microsoft Databases for usage in enterprise?

Tags: database, mysql, sql-server, oracle-database

Lets take this: Company using Microsoft Server Database since 2008. Its company what heavily depends on working with data from databases. (Construction company ) Current database is outdated and not very structured because people what was working on it in 2008 developed it fast and not very intelligently.

I decided to suggest them rebuild of current database structure to make everything clearer, faster and more reliable.

My main question is if there are any main differences between MySQL (MariaDB), PostgreSQL, Oracle, Microsoft database systems. I know that using "paid" databases is "always better" but I dont see any differences in performance or reliability of these relational databases.
Are there any? If yes, why they are better for usage in enterprise project instead of others (Do not answer to last question if u thing its option based)?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 1):

1. Oracle has no customers, they have hostages only.
2. Microsoft SQL Server is well designed database with a lot of documentation accessible. However it works on Microsoft platforms mostly, which gives you a lot of headache, and is licensing nightmare, specially when connected with virtualization
3. MySQL work at best with clusters, as single platform is not so stable as any of two above.
4. Postgresql is the best choice, of course if you are skilled in postgresql...

More seriously: it depends on various things, like availability, ability to manage, time you can afford to spend on it, sizes of databases, your infrastructure, times of response required etc.

Comment: Lets say that database have many dozens of databases. Every database about thousand rows of bookkeeping data and few tables with images saved as BLOBs (about 2MB per image). This databases needs to be 24/7/365 online. Access is not so big (only few people at once) viewing tables and uploading some images.Response time is not important. Time spent on dev is not important. What u can say about it now

Comment: At least three of these are worth to check without any expenses. As most cases database is used with virtualization, check licensing terms. The best approach is to just check it by testing. The only advice I have is stay away oracle ( any!) technology as long as you can...